# Postgres keeps transaction idle after killing the program that created it

Tags: postgresql

My Postgres 9.2 seems to keep some transactions in idle status, even after killing the program the created it.

Example: I open a transaction in a program, then I debug the program from Visual Studio, then I stop the debugging and the program is killed.

But the PgAdmin still show the transaction as idle:

[image]

No VSHost or similar process are active, the transaction remains idle even after closing the Visual Studio or shutting down the pc.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the TCP keep  alive and/or timeouts

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm trying to find out if there is some PG setting. Can you help me?